# Is operator support required for standard NFTs?

Tags: wallets, fa2, nft

I'm making my first FA2-based NFT contract and I want to reduce the amount of code by sacking the operator logic. To be clear, I'm still following the FA2 interface, but the entrypoint now looks like this (in Camel Ligo):

```
Update_operators updates ->
      (failwith "FA2_OPERATORS_UNSUPPORTED" : (operation  list) * storage)
```

Question: will the NFTs from this contract still show up normally in all the standard wallets, or is this going to cause compatibility problems? If it will cause problems, can you please elaborate on the point of operators for NFTs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting an Operator allows another wallet / contract address to transfer or make use of the asset that was given to it.

This is how all dApps work. If you want to sell something on objkt.com, you have to make the objkt contract an operator of the thing you are trying to sell. If you want to use an app to swap an NFT with another person, you need to make that app an operator of your NFT.

Long story short, removing this would mean that your NFT's would not be able to integrate into any other dApp. You would also not be able to build any kind of marketplace / swap on your side either, for second hand sales. This would be an incredibly bad idea, and may mean certain indexers and/or wallets are unable to support your asset.

Please always stick to the full standard, always